# Parsing XML using GDataXML returns a NSString object with a retainCount of 95.How to ensure it gets released?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, gdataxml

The NSString object that is got by the following code has got a retainCount of 95.

```
for(GDataXMLElement *ele in [doc.rootElement elementsForName:@"myKey"])
    {
        NSLog(@"myKey %d",[[[ele.children objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] retainCount]);

        [myDict setObject:[[ele.children objectAtIndex:0] stringValue] forKey:@"myKey"];

    }
```

. so would it get released later when

```
[myDict removeAllObjects];
[myDict release];
```

is called.

the problem i am facing is that i have hundreds of strings like this parsed.... and all their retaincounts are around 95...would these strings get released?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the problem i am facing is that i have hundreds of strings like this
>   parsed.... and all their retaincounts are around 95...would these
>   strings get released?

**First, `retainCount` is useless**.   Don't call it.  No, really, [don't use retainCount](http://www.whentouseretaincount.com/).

To answer your question, look to Instruments.   Do the objects that you expect to go away actually stay in memory?   If so, then turn on reference count tracking and see what still holds references to them (or what retains are unbalanced).

More likely than not, the XML subsystem is unique-ifying the strings such that only one copy of what may be repeated hundreds of times is in memory.   That one copy may be retained dozens or hundreds of times as a result.   When you `removeAllObjects` from `myDict`, there may still be a reference to the objects.  It might even be an `autorelease`d reference and, thus, will actually go away.

The only way to know is to look to see if the objects are deallocated via Instruments (or some other means).

Answer (score 1):

As per the definitions & explanations given by many others including raywinderlich in his [How To Choose The Best XML Parser for Your iPhone Project](http://www.raywenderlich.com/553/how-to-chose-the-best-xml-parser-for-your-iphone-project).

[GDataXML](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/XMLSupport/) is nothing but a NSXML style DOM XML parser for the iPhone, developed by Google as part of their Objective-C client library. Consisting of just a M file and a header, it supports both reading and writing XML documents and XPath queries.

A **DOM parser** reads the entire document and builds up an in-memory representation that you can query for different elements. Often, you can even construct XPath queries to pull out particular pieces.

So it just creates a tree like structure for the given entire XML, each elements can be queried to pull particular pieces.

And as we know this all works with the pointers, so what ever elements we get from this tree will be just pointing to that object, with the same name(used while initializing xml) or a new name while pulling particular pieces(using `NSXMLElement`).

And so everything will be retained until we release the XMLDoc while initializing XML.

If you want we can check the retain counts after releasing the XMLDoc(but it may give crash as are we using released object).

I think it works in this way, if you or other developers have any other info on this share your info.

Comment: but even after the gdataxml doc is released... the retaincount of it is still 95. with such a large retaincount i doubt even if i release the dictionary ..will it get released?